# Dolphin doesn't show hidden files in search results

Tags: kubuntu, kde, search, plasma, dolphin

I installed kubuntu on my new laptop. I decided to give it a try after Ubuntu Gnome/Mate/xfce.

One of the problems I have with this environment is search results in Dolphin. It doesn't show any hidden files in my home folder nor any files/directories which are in hidden folders. For example, I try to find Chrome folder which is `~/.cache/google-chrome/`. I type `google-chrome` in the search edit box and get nothing.

I enabled showing hidden files in Dolphin.

After some search I found information about the `baloofilerc` file and now it looks like this:

```
[General]
dbVersion=2
exclude filters=
exclude filters version=5
first run=false
folders[$e]=/mnt/third/,/home/dima/,/mnt/second/,/mnt/windows/,/
index hidden files=true
index hidden folders=true
only basic indexing=true
```